# Git How do I Push a project, that was Downloaded from Source

Tags: git, github

I worked with a graphic designer that did not clone from my github account. He downloaded the project from source rather than using the command "git clone". Since he pulled his files, a month has gone by and I want to do the following tasks:

1. Create a new branch
2. Push the graphic designers project into that branch
3. Merge his branch with Master

I've tried the following the [github](http://help.github.com/forking/) forking guide with not much luck; when I attempt to push the files into a new branch I get an error: `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using an existing checkout. First, create a branch to store the designer's changes:

```
git checkout -b graphics
```

Next, copy his files on top of the existing files in that project. You can use `git status` to confirm that you've got all the files. Then, commit the changes to that new branch.

You can then merge that branch into `master` using the usual merge methods.

Answer (score 0):

Clone the repository, make the branch, check it out, put the files in place, add, commit, push.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into `rebase --onto`

Basically, init a git repo in the designer's working directory, let him commit his work as a first commit.

then add a remote to your github, fetch it, then rebase his local master --onto the github master

Note: I haven't tried this myself, so you might wanna try it on a dummy project first.

```
git init
git add <stuff>
git commit -m"designer's work"
git remote add hub <github-clone-url>
git fetch hub
git rebase --onto hub/master
```